As an advisor, how can I help students with time management and procrastination?
As an advisor, I've worked with students who have dealt with issues including time management, procrastination, and discouragement. (I've also dealt with some of these same issues myself.)
I understand that the transition from undergraduate to graduate studies can be very difficult: there is much less structure, nobody is constantly telling you exactly what to do and when to do it, and the student is largely responsible for devising their own goals.
I'd like to be more helpful to my advisees in this regard. What are some useful strategies which I might adopt?

Indirectly, teach by example.
For example, model time management by not waiting until the last minute.
Set goals.
Model work-life balance.
Break larger projects into smaller projects.
Also, with by example, tell and show your students what you are doing.
You might tell them, I am doing X, to build to Y that will lead to Z.
You can also help them see how they fit into the bigger picture of your research group (if your field operates like this).
Directly, train them to learn these skills for themselves.
For a new grad student, you might have weekly check-in meetings and assign them goals the next week and tell them the big picture goals.
For a more experience grad student, have them set their own short-term goals and have them link these into their own goals.
For an almost complete grad student, possibly no time management is needed.
Furthermore, some students may need more help than others or different help.
Meet students where they are at.
Finally, refer students to resources at your university (and, if possible, show your students these events are okay to attend by telling them about your own professional development activities).
Some have graduate schools with programs and workshops that teach these skills.
My PhD school has activities like an End-of-Semester Graduate Writing Retreat and restorative yoga.

As you say, a big part of the challenge is the sudden lack of structure - so help them build that structure back in. I have ADHD and my supervisors do an amazing job of supporting me. I also have a "specialist mentor", funded by the university, who I meet every two weeks to talk about time management strategies.
Some of the things that help me:

Regular, structured meetings
Emailed summary after each meeting
Breaking deliverables down into smaller tasks
Clear feedback on where I'm doing well and where I need to improve
Setting expectations: what is "good enough" and what is excellent

Regular, structured meetings
We meet every two weeks. They asked me to make a set of slides before each meeting, covering progress, plans, problems and publications. The progress slide covers what I've done since our previous meeting, plans is what I think I need to do next, problems is anything I'm stuck on, and publications is any upcoming publications I'm working on. We go through the slides to structure the meeting, and I edit them as we talk. This means that at the end of the meeting, the plans slide is our shared understanding of what I need to do next, and the problems slide has notes on our discussion of how to solve any problems I'm having. This structure helps me a lot with time management, as I have a clear plan of what I should be working on.
Emailed summary after each meeting
After each meeting I type up the notes from the slides and email my supervisors a summary of what we discussed and what I'm working on next. This helps with accountability, which I find very helpful to avoid procrastination.
Breaking deliverables down into smaller tasks
If I'm stuck on a big chunk of work and don't know how to tackle it, we talk through it and work out smaller tasks that are more manageable. This helps me avoid procrastination, as it's easier to start one small task that I can actually finish.
Clear feedback on where I'm doing well and where I need to improve
My supervisors give me great feedback. They're clear about how my work can improve, especially when giving feedback on writing. They also tell me when I'm doing well, which is important for motivation! The reason their feedback is good is that it's specific about what the problems are and how I can address them. For example, "This paragraph just restates what is in the table, it would be improved if you pull out some interesting examples and discuss those."
Setting expectations: what is "good enough" and what is excellent
I want to do excellent work, but sometimes when I'm struggling I just need to settle for "good enough". If I'm having problems with a particular piece of work, I talk to my supervisors about what is the minimum and what are nice-to-haves. Sometimes it turns out the minimum is actually very achievable, and then I can tackle nice-to-haves without worrying that I'm failing completely. Proactively talking through what adequate and excellent looks like can be really helpful to avoid discouragement, because if you've only talked about what the ideal outcome would be then anything less can feel like failure.

Actually, I'd suggest calling in the professionals. Most universities will have some sort of office that has people with some expertise in this. For individual advisees, you could suggest a visit to the office for advice.
If you are teaching a class, however, it seems valid to me to invite that office to hold a session with your class, taking half an hour or so to give advice. I've had to spend time in class giving pointers on effective note taking (CS course) that helped the students deal more effectively with lectures (a different question, of course) and it was worth the time spent in helping them up their game.
At a minimum, you could visit such an office yourself and get pointers there.

As a graduate student, I faced procrastination issues, lack of motivation issues, occasional self-doubt issues, and ego issues. It got so bad that my PhD advisor had to step in at some point with an email that described my situation at the time and suggested that I send a report every week with my goals for the week, including monthly goals that were supposed to be met every month, which did help me get back on track.
Additionally, something I discovered as a postdoc, was that engaging with 2 to 3 different projects at the same time tremendously helps with my productivity. The projects need not be large, I'm talking about small chunks of some bigger work plus your main project. To make it more concrete, my field is physics. One project might be analyzing data from a fellow graduate student's project, another might be my project, and another might be writing software to calculate something.
Other ideas that can help are regular meetings where you motivate your students' projects and show them how they fit in the bigger picture including the whole field itself. Moreover, try to get them involved in anything you do, such as grant writing, teaching, conferences, etc., and try to be close to them as much as possible (via emails, meetings, group meetings, etc.).

I completely agree about the value of having at least two projects. There was a phase during my PhD when I only had one, and when I was struggling to make progress on that one project it made me substantially less willing to keep engaging with it (because what's the point... it won't work today either), which wasn't great for my productivity or overall mental state.

I recommend handling interactions with the student as if you were managing a project (well-- in fact, you are managing a project, so it's not that tough of a stretch).
Work with the student to develop a timetable for interim check-ins and milestone reviews.  Ask the student to lay out their own dates for the milestone reviews, and to keep a task-list with self-generated deadlines that the student believes are achievable such that progress is constant, ongoing, and transparent.  Teach the student the tools they need to know in order to know whether they are on time, or starting to lag.
Start by encouraging the student to make the deadlines extra generous so you get a few outcomes in the "win" column to start.  Keep track of progress, and help the student learn what their capabilities are.  I teach a projects based course, and I encourage the students to not overestimate their capabilities.  For example, if an inexperienced student believes something will take an hour, it seems far more likely that it will take a day, and if they think it will take a day, it's more likely that a week will be closer to the right number.
For a number of reasons, for people in your situation, I recommend a book called "Project Management" by a guy named Heerkens.  It will teach you about coordinating with a team in a way that everyone who needs to understands who is responsible for what and when.  Even more important, Heerkens talks about something he calls the "accidental manager" -- which really resonated with me when I saw it.  There are a lot of parallels between the accidental manager and the academic mentor.

You did not mention the subject you are teaching.
Introduce them to scrum and kanban if that is not common in your field. While it is not perfect for research tasks, and not designed for single-person 'teams,' it can be helpful to visualize things which should be done, and things which have successfully been done.
If feasible, chair regular meetings with all of your graduate students where they discuss partial results and lines of research. It might be problematic if the research turns into a team effort, but being able to present in front of a small, known audience might help to prepare them for conferences, etc.
